# Why is the space of differential forms $\bigoplus_{p=0}^n \Lambda_x^p$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, direct-sum

In Wald's book "General Relativity", the space $\Lambda_x$ of differential forms at a point $x$ is worked out in the following manner: Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold. The vector space of all $p$-forms at a point $x \in M$ is given by $\Lambda_x^p$. The vector space $\Lambda_x$ of all differential forms (not limited to a specified degree $p$) is given by the direct sum:

$$
\Lambda_x =\bigoplus_{p=0}^n \Lambda_x^p
$$

However, from my understanding, the direct sum $A \oplus B$ of two spaces $A$ and $B$ consists of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, with the additional structure:

$$(a_1, b_1) + (a_2, b_2) = (a_1 + a_2, b_1 + b_2)$$

Wouldn't this mean that an element from $\omega \in \Lambda_x$ would take the form:

$$
\omega = (\omega_1, \omega_2, \dots , \omega_n)
$$

where $\omega_1$ is a 1-form, $\omega_2$ a 2-form, and so on? This to me doesn't seem to be the space of all differential forms at $x$, unless all $\omega_i$ are 0 except one for each $\omega$. In fact, it seems to be a much larger space, since it can contain multiple differential forms of different degrees. My first guess was that a $p$-form and a $q$-form would be combined via the map $ \bigwedge: \Lambda^p_x \times \Lambda^q_x \mapsto \Lambda^{p+q}_x $, but then we are no longer limited to the degree $n$. Why is this written as a direct sum rather than, for example, a union?

$$
\Lambda_x = \bigcup_{p=0}^n \Lambda_x^p
$$

Comment: It might be useful to note where you learned the notation from, so that potential answers can work with potential nuance in the rest of the text

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks! I'm reading "General Relativity" by Wald, and this is taken from Appendix B. I don't know whether it will help, but I added it to the question for clarification.

Comment: My suspicion is this is what's called the exterior algebra of the tangent space at the point $x$.  Remember, when a space is finite dimensional of dimension say $n$ then any $p$ form with $p>n$ is necessarily 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give a brief description of the exterior algebra if that helps.  There are a few ways to go about this but I will take the one that is hopefully the most clear.

Let's start with a vector space $V$.  Remember in our context $V$ is the tangent space to the manifold at a given point and we actually get a whole family of spaces that vary in a smooth way as you move around the manifold (change the base point of the tangent space).  Now, we wish to consider all alternating forms on $V$ which are by definition multi-linear maps that satisfy an alternating condition.  For example a 2-form satisfies
$$\omega(x_1,x_2)=-\omega(x_2,x_1)$$
and an $k$-form satisfies
$$\omega(x_{\sigma(1)},...,x_{\sigma(k)})=sgn(\sigma)\omega(x_1,...,x_k)$$
where $\sigma$ is a permutation on $k$ letters and $sgn(\sigma)$ (the signature)  is either 1 or -1 depending upon $\sigma$.

**Remark**
The alternating condition forces any $m$-form with $m>n$ variables to be exactly $0$.  You can see this by realizing that if a set of vectors $v_1,...,v_k$ are linearly dependent, then for any $k$-form $\eta$ we have $\eta(v_1,...,v_k)=0$.  You can show this by induction on a 2-form.  For example $\eta(x,cx)=c\eta(x,x)$ now interchange the two entries and the alternating condition forces $\eta(x,x)=-\eta(x,x)$ which means $\eta(x,x)=0$.  What do you know about a set of vectors $v_1,...,v_m$ in a vector space $V$ with $dim(V)=n$ and $m>n$?

Now we wish to construct an object with a multiplication that contains all such maps.  We see that there will be $n+1$ distinct classes of objects: the $k$-forms for $k=0,...,n$.
We define the collection
$$\Lambda^k(V)=\{\text{alternating}\quad k-\text{linear maps on}\quad V\}$$
You can check that $\Lambda^k(V)$ is a vector space and that its dimension is $n\choose k$.

It makes sense to organize them as $n+1$-tuples where the $k$'th entry is $\Lambda^k(V)$.
The multiplication comes from the wedge product which you mentioned in your post.  The wedge product sends you up the ladder of forms but necessarily stops at $n$ because of the above remark. So we can consider the object
$$\Lambda(V)=\bigoplus_{k=0}^n \Lambda^k(V) $$
What does an element $\lambda\in \Lambda(V)$ look like?
$$\lambda=(\omega_0,...,\omega_n)$$ with $\omega_k\in \Lambda^k(V)$.

In the context of differential geometry, we now have such a collection defined at every point on the manifold $M$ and the coefficients are not just scalars but can be smooth functions on $M$.  To understand these objects a bit more formalism is required such as the idea of tangent bundles and so on but I won't get into this here.

Why are differential forms important?  Well, they can be integrated over the manifold in a straightforward way and allows one to define volume on a manifold. Of course, in the context of physics they are important because they are tensors and tensors allow one to discover invariant object on $M$ (coordinate independent). You will see that Einstein's field equations of gravitation are statements about certain tensors on spacetime; the Ricci curvature tensor $R_{\mu \nu}$ and energy momentum tensor $T_{\mu \nu}$.  These are not necessarily differential forms but they can be understood and constructed with these concepts.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I read through your post quickly as I'm outside at the moment but will read it again thoroughly when I get home. Before I accept it (and if this question doesn't make sense, I'll get back to you when I've read it thoroughly), couldn't several forms be represented by the same object in $\Lambda(V)$? For example, $(0, \omega_1, \omega_2, 0)$ and $(0, 0, 0, \omega_3)$, if the combination of $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ maps into $\omega_3$? I think I understand the rest of your answer but am just a bit confused as to why this way of organizing it makes sense.

Comment: @Max What combination of $\omega_1, \omega_2$ do you mean? A wedge product could make this happen but that takes you up to the fourth coordinate.  If you write the objects with respect to a basis this can help.

Comment: Exactly, I referred to the case $\omega_3 = \omega_1 \wedge \omega_2$. Basically, my thinking goes like this: Each element from $\Lambda(V)$ represents a specific differential form in $V$. The only way this made sense to me is if (for example) $(0, \omega_1, 0)$ is used to represent $\omega_1$, and $(0, 0, \omega_2)$ to represent $\omega_2$. But then, what is $(0, \omega_1, \omega_2)$? If it is $\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2$, then wouldn't that mean that the same differential form (in some cases) can be represented by several vectors in $\Lambda(V)$?

Comment: @ Max First of all, if you are just on e vector space $V$ there are just forms, alternating forms etc. the differentiable structure comes when we go to a manifold. Second, $(0,\omega_1,0)$ and $\omega_1$ are different objects; they live in different spaces.  The wedge product (to my knowledge) is not defined on $\Lambda(V)$ but rather on any pair of $\Lambda^n(V),\Lambda^m(V)$

Comment: Aren't elements in $\Lambda(V)$ supposed to represent all forms on $V$? I thought an element in $\Lambda(V)$ corresponded to exactly one alternating form (of order between 0 and $n$)? I understand that $(0, \omega_1, 0)$ and $\omega_1$ are different objects (and the suggested "equivalence" between them was only an example), but if each element in $\Lambda(V)$ would correspond to a form, then there has to be a pairing somehow. What you're saying now however seems to reveal that my interpretation of $\Lambda(V)$ is wrong. But in that case, what does an element in $\Lambda(V)$ represent exactly?

Comment: I'm no expert on the subject but I have always viewed it as an abstract vector space that contains all possible forms which are ordered in a way called a graded algebra.  It's a quotient of a larger object called the tensor algebra $T(V)$ which is always infinite dimensional.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I think it's clear now that I misinterpreted the space $\Lambda(V)$, and that the way to understand this further is to look into graded algebra (and tensor algebra). This does answer my initial question!

Comment: By the way: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2349194/203427 From this answer it seems like $\Lambda(V)$ consists of elements with mixed ordered forms (for example $\omega_1 + \omega_2$). For some reason I didn't consider this possible, but if this is true, then I understand why it is a direct sum (in this case, graded algebra).

Answer (score 2):

I would consider it as the space of formal sums of differential forms. So an element in the space might be $3dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge dx_3 - 19dx_1 \wedge dx_2 + 4$. The operations like $\wedge$ and addition still make sense if you extend them by linearity.

Comment: Thank you! This confirms the conclusion made in the comments in the other answer!